# I get confused with Form.Close()

Tags: winforms, delegates, formclosing

So I link delegate from Form2 to This_Hide() fuction in Form1, then i link delegate from Form3 to delegate in Form2(which link to function in Form1 as I said) but I get confused that it still work although Form2 is CLOSED when I making instance of Form3. If Form.Close() method closes Form2 and dispose it how delegate from Form3 can still call function(delegate) from Form2..?

```
    namespace TestingMachine
    {
        public delegate void FxDelegate();

        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {


            }

            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Form2 fr2 = new Form2();
                fr2.Delegate_Father_Hide = new FxDelegate(This_Hide);
                fr2.Show();
            }

            public void This_Hide()
            {
                this.Hide();
            }
        }
    }

    namespace TestingMachine
    {
        public partial class Form2 : Form
        {
            public FxDelegate Delegate_Father_Hide;

            public Form2()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {


            }

            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Form3 fr3 = new Form3();
                fr3.Delegate_Hide_Grandfather = new FxDelegate(Hide_Grandfather);
                fr3.Show();
                this.Close();

            }

            public void Hide_Grandfather()
            {
                Delegate_Father_Hide();
            }
        }
    }

    namespace TestingMachine
    {
        public partial class Form3 : Form
        {
            public FxDelegate Delegate_Hide_Grandfather;

            public Form3()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Delegate_Hide_Grandfather();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Disposing a form cleans up resources being used. But by attaching the callback method `Hide_Grandfather` to the delegate `Delegate_Hide_Grandfather`, the `Form3` object holds a reference to the `Form2` object, so it cannot be marked for GC cleanup, the object remains in memory and works (depending on what you are doing there). But I recommend to clean up your code.